# What does 'col.names' do in 'as.data.frame' in R?

Tags: r

I'm using `as.data.frame()` function to turn a table into dataframe in R, and I would like to set column names with the function.

I found that there's an optional argument for `as.data.frame(),` which is `col.names`.

The documentation says that it's a character vector of column names. However, whatever I put in `col.names`, the result keeps the same.

```
x = c('a','b','c','a')
x_table = table(x)
x_df = as.data.frame(x_table, col.names = c('name', 'freq'))
```

Output here is:

```
    x Freq
1   a    2
2   b    1
3   c    1
```

I understand I could use `colnames(df)` to change the column names after the dataframe is created, but I really wonder why `col.names` does not work here.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi ZHI LIU, can you please give us an example of your code, so we may better understand why your results are not as expected? Thanks

Comment: Because you have an object of class `table`, the method called is `as.data.frame.table` which does _not_ have a `col.names` argument.

Comment: Hi Justin, I've added an example.  And I'm wondering whether I used the wrong word to describe the type of the output of function `table()`. Is that a 'table'?

Comment: Thank you Henrik! I understand.

Comment: @Henrik according to the R documentation, as.data.frame does have a "col.names" argument

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to avoid assigning the column names after creating the dataframe, you can utilize the `dnn` parameter in the `table` function to specify your "name" column, and the `responseName` parameter in the `as.data.frame` function to specify the "freq" column.

```
x <- c('a','b','c','a')
x_df <- as.data.frame(table(x, dnn = list("name")), responseName = "freq")
```

Comment: Why doesn't the col.names argument work?

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a class error as @Henrik pointed out. Using this code I can get the correct names, but call an error

```
x=c('a','b','c','a')
x_table=table(x)
x_df=as.data.frame(x_table,colnames(x_df)<-c("name","freq"))

>x_df
  name freq
1    a    2
2    b    1
3    c    1
```

Error in data.frame(do.call("expand.grid", c(dimnames(provideDimnames(x,  : 
    row names supplied are of the wrong length

If I set,

```
row.names=NULL
```

In the same line of code, the un-named Df is spit back out again, but no error.

Best guess is a formatting/class error.