# Can anyone provide a working example of using col.names in as.data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Can anyone provide a working example of using `col.names` in `as.data.frame`?

Similar questions have been asked before: 
[What does 'col.names' do in 'as.data.frame' in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741812/what-does-col-names-do-in-as-data-frame-in-r) 
[Why is as.data.frame ignoring col.names = vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327408/why-is-as-data-frame-ignoring-col-names-vector) 
And workarounds have been offered, but I have yet to see an example actually using `col.names` and an explanation why. Can it do something useful?

Comment: The question was marked as duplicate but in the link for this I see no explanation. Actually, none of the two answers even mentions the `col.names` argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the list method has this parameter. You can see that in the *Usage* section of `help("as.data.frame")`.

A working example, which might be considered "something useful":

```
as.data.frame(list(1, 2), col.names = c("a", "b"))
#  a b
#1 1 2
```